# My code is only inserting the last file name into my database. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, file, insert

This code echoes all filenames from a specified directory but only inserts the name of the last file in the folder into the database. What must I do to get all the file names in the directory into the database? Many thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypswrd";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$dir = "myFiles";    // directory path to files
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo $file . "</br>";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (fileName) VALUES ('$file')";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The part of your code that performs the insertion is not `$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (fileName) VALUES ('$file')";`, it's `($conn->query($sql)`. BTW, you'd better drop the book or tutorial that taught you to inject raw input into SQL code as in `('$file')`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. Yes I realise I need to add some validation. I've got a lot to learn! (This script will only be used to help me build my database on my local network.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because  your "if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE" is outside the while loop.

You're building your $sql inside the while loop, but you only execute the query after the  while loop, hence you're only inserting last record.

//Suggestion

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypswrd";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$dir = "myFiles";    // directory path to files
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
         echo $file . "</br>";
          $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (fileName) VALUES ('$file')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
        else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
         }
        closedir($dh);


    }
  }

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. It worked perfectly and was a big help!